# Copado Roboti Testing - "QWebDriverError: No browser open. Use OpenBrowser keyword to open browser first" error appears in tests

Tags: robotframework, crt

[image: Error messages]

This is the error i get when i try to run the tests in VS Code. Im using Copado Robotic Testing that is based on Robot Framework.
I have the QWeb library installed. The following are the settings options i use:

```
*** Settings ***
Library                   QWeb
Library                   String
# Resource                  sf_rest_api.robot
Resource                  utils.robot
#Resource                  ../config/variables_QA.robot
Resource                  ../config/variables_qa_ecom.robot
# Resource                  helper_kwords.robot
```

I expected for my tests to pass. I tried to re-install QWeb library, restart VSC and still i get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it seems that you have not opened a browser prior to running the tests.

You have not shared your tests here. However, based on the error message in your logs, I infer that you have not initiated a browser. Try OpenBrowser with a url before your test steps or as a suite setup.

OpenBrowser           http://google.com    chrome

https://docs.copado.com/articles/#!copado-robotic-testing-publication/all-qwords